# Can't change Database in Neo4j

Tags: macos, neo4j, database, nosql

I'm using Neo4j for mac and I'm trying to change the database, I changed the "Neo4j-Server.proprieties" under /conf to "org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db" restarted the neo4j but when I open the browser "localhost:7474/browser/", I still have an akward path !!!

**Location:
/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.2/libexec/data/graph.db**

How can I change that patch to link it to my database ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied an absolute path, have you tried:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/data/graph.db
```

Comment: Yes I tried and nothing, I still have the same awkward patch in the local host !!